# Use of SPRequest class in SharePoint Object Model

Tags: object-model

Can any one explain what exactly does SPRequest class do and for what function we must use it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... it is an internal class, so most of the time you should not brother directly with it. Basically it is a wrapper for the unmanaged SP.SPRequest class which is in turn used by almost any read/write operation performed by the SharePoint object model.
You can refer to [this great blog post](http://hristopavlov.wordpress.com/2009/01/19/understanding-sharepoint-sprequest/) for further detail (it is just to long to copy all the material here). From my experience there should be no need to use it directly.